# Jquery validation to match email fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i have this html code:

```
<p>
 <label for="email">E-mail</label>
 <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="ex: email@gmail.com"/>
</p>        
<p>
<label for="email_alt">E-mail Alternativo</label>
<input id="email_alt" name="email_alt" />
</p>
```

and i want to validate if the emails match in running time.

i found the code below in one of the posts here in stackoverflow and i understand that #author_email and #author_confirm_email are the id's of the inputs. And as far was i know .blur is to trigger the alert in running time. but i'm not understanding that ".email" that trigger the function. What can i use there considerating the code i have?

```
   $(".email").blur(function(){
  //check to two here.
  if ($("#author_email").val() != $("#author_confirm_email").val())
  {
    //do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the fields at runtime (i.e. while the user is typing), you have to use the `keyup` event (this event is fired each time a user has pressed and released a key):

```
$("#email_alt").keyup(function(){
    if ($("#email").val() != $("#email_alt").val()) {
        // emails don't match
    }
});
```

Didn't test this, but actually it should work like that.

You might want to add some further validation, e.g. prevent empty fields and assure valid email addresses (as GTSouza suggested).

Answer (score 2):

The blur event is triggered whenever the object loses focus (ie someone presses tab or clicks the next input box). Note that the "." signifies a class, whereas "#" is an ID. So in that code, every time something with a class name of "email" loses focus, that validation function is called.

Answer (score 0):

//

```
input#email
```

//

```
input#email-confirm
```

//

```
function IsValidEmail(a){var b=/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;return b.test(a)}

var validate = true;
$('input[name*="email"]:visible', $(this)).each(function(index, field){
            if(!IsValidEmail($(field).val()) && validate){
                $(field).focus().addClass('invalid');
                validate = false;
                return false;
            }

            var confirm = $('#'+$(field).attr('id')+'-confirm');
            if(confirm.size() > 0){
                if($(field).val() != $(confirm).val()){
                    $(field).focus().addClass('invalid');
                    validate = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```